# Windows 10 CouchDB 1.5.0 service doesn't start automatically after reboot?

Tags: database, runtime-error, windows-10, couchdb, reboot

When i restart my Windows 10 Pro PC i see that the CouchDB Service doesn't start and i get a Event Log Error in the Error always stands **"Apache CouchDB01d2f00de476fcd0: Could not get registry keys for erlang serivce."** So we tryed to edit the regedit ore something but we doesn't see any problems why the service doesn't start.

Comment: You have tryed [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/748736/apache-couchdb-service-terminates-on-windows-10-single-language) ?

Comment: Yeah :D I tryed it already :(